# ¿Cómo abrir varios archivos .fxml en javaFX dentro de la misma Ventana?

Tags: java, javafx

Tengo un ligero problema que no he podido resolver por el momento y es el siguiente:
Lo único que requiero es que al dar click en un botón dentro de mi sistema quisiera que el nuevo archivo .fxml que estoy llamando se abra pero en la misma ventana. Esto es para evitar que haya muchas ventanas cada vez que se haga el click.

En este momento el código abre mi .fxml pero en otra nueva ventana y eso le quita funcionalidad a mi sistema. Aquí esta mi código:

```
    public void Registro() throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../Vista/Registros/RegistroDeciscion.fxml"));
    Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    stage.setTitle("Ayuda");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
    stage.show();   
}
```

Así es como actualmente funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que todas esas ventanas se abran en el mismo Escenario, Esto para evitar una redundancia de muchas ventanas dentro del mismo programa.

Answer (score 4):

Muy bien como sé que esta pregunta lleva varios meses, yo la encontré buscando exactamente una solución al mismo problema. Sin embargo, no había respuesta correcta, así que investigué y encontré la forma de abrir distintos archivos fxml en la misma ventana.

Creando un proyecto JavaFX FXML Application, el nombre que se le dé a la aplicación, será tomado en el archivo main, ahí se deberá modificar el código y cambiarlo como este:

```
public class Cierre extends Application {
    //Estos son objetos que llamaremos abajo
    Button btn, btn2; //botones que mandaran a llamar a la ventana que deseamos abrir
    Label lbl, lbl2;// Label para colocar texto e identificar las ventanas en este ejemplo
    Scene scene, scene2;//con esto cargaremos el contenido de cada ventana un scene por cada una
    Stage thestage;// este Stage se utiliza para cargar la ventana se puede utilizar con todas las ventanas
```

E inicializamos:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    thestage=stage; 
    btn=new Button();
    btn2=new Button();
    btn.setOnAction(e-> ButtonClicked(e));//Indicamos que hará una acción cuando se dé clic en el botón
    btn2.setOnAction(e-> ButtonClicked(e));
   /* lbl=new Label("Scene 1");
      lbl2=new Label("Scene 2");*/
```

Podriamos declarar el label desde aquí, pero yo lo haré desde Scene builder, así que quedará comentado, continuando con el código

Parent nos ayuda a declarar dónde buscará el archivo fxml, abajo entre comillas se escribe la ruta del archivo. En mi caso, los dos fxml están dentro del mismo paquete para facilitar la carga. Al final explicaré cómo agregar el otro archivo fxml.

```
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
    Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Nueva.fxml"));
    scene = new Scene(root);// indicamos qué scene contendrá el Parent de cada ventana
    scene2 = new Scene(root2);

    stage.setTitle("Hello World!");//Esto no es necesario a menos que deses colocar un titulo, iria entre comillas
    stage.setScene(scene);//declaras la escena de la ventana, en este caso sera la principal
    stage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

private void ButtonClicked(ActionEvent e) {
    //aquí en caso de presionar algún boton se declara qué escena deseamos ejecutar
    //esto podría teóricamente cambiarse con un switch, pero en este caso sólo hacemos intercambio entre dos escenas
    if (e.getSource()==btn)
        thestage.setScene(scene2);
    else
        thestage.setScene(scene);
}}
```

Seleccionando el paquete contenedor de nuestro archivo main, damos clic derecho, nuevo, y seleccionamos en Otro, buscamos Empty FXM, seleccionamos siguiente y colocamos un nombre, y damos siguiente, seleccionamos Use Java Controller, para crear el archivo controlador donde meteremos nuestros métodos, Siguiente y terminar, el nombre completo de nuestro fxml será el que ingresemos entre comillas en el Parent.

Abrimos el fxml principal, por lo general se llama fxmlDocument.fxml, en scene builder agregamos un botón, y un label. Al label le colocamos "Escena 1" y al botón "Ir a Escena 2". Teniendo seleccionado el botón, expandimos la sección Code en el lateral derecho, y le colocamos nombre como id, y en `OnAction` igualmente colocamos un nombre haciendo referencia a que hará algo. Guardamos y en nuetro fxml que acabos de guardar damos clic derecho y MakeController, con ello agregamos el código de nuestro botón al FxmlDocumentController.java. Lo abrimos, y dentro de nuestro Event handler del botón que creamos colocaremos el siguiente código y modificaremos el evento también:

```
@FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{ //vamos agregar el throws IOException
        Stage stage; 
     Parent root;
     if(event.getSource()==btn){
        //Obtener referencia a la Escena del botón         
        stage=(Stage) btn.getScene().getWindow();
        //cargar el otro documento, en este caso la segundo pantalla
  root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Nueva.fxml"));
      }
     else{
       stage=(Stage) btn2.getScene().getWindow();
  root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
      }
     //Crear una nueva escena con raíz y establecer el escenario
      Scene scene = new Scene(root);
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
    }
```

Creo que no es necesario colocar el código del `else`, y así podremos quitar el `if`, pero tendremos que colocar el código que está en el `if` dentro de un `try catch` en caso de que nos suceda algún error al cargar la nueva escena, y el código que está después del `else` también tendría que estar en el `try`.

Bueno, con esto podremos abrir la segunda ventana, y para el controller de la segunda ventana agregamos el mismo código en la acción del botón. Agregamos el `throw` también. 
-"Si lo puedes imaginar, lo puedes programar".

Answer (score 0):

¿No tienes control sobre el `stage` actual? Podrías declararlo globalmente para tener control sobre él y cambiarle la escena.

Supongamos que tienes el `stage` actual en el objeto `currentStage`:

```
public void Registro() throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../Vista/Registros/RegistroDeciscion.fxml"));
    Parent root1          = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
    Scene newScene        = new Scene(root1);

    currentStage.setTitle("Ayuda");
    currentStage.setScene(newScene);  
    //currentStage.show(); Esto ya no sería necesario, hemos de deducir que ya se ha hecho un show del currentStage anteriomente
}
```

Fuente: http://www.javafxtutorials.com/tutorials/switching-to-different-screens-in-javafx-and-fxml/

También he visto otra forma de hacerlo aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619394/loading-new-fxml-in-the-same-scene

En esta segunda opción modifica directamente el contenido de la ventana añadiéndole un FXML a uno de sus elementos (no directamente cambiando la escena).